# python flask+gevent doesn't release memory. limit.conf

Tags: python, events, memory, flask

```
#packages.
greenlet==0.4.11
Flask==0.11.1

#centos, /etc/security/limit.conf
* soft nofile 65535
* hard nofile 65535
```

This is my test codes (python 3.5) I ran this and watched memory usage.

At First, It started with 30MB memory with 3 threads.
But After sending bulk "/do" request on this server, 
memory increase to 60MB with 12 threads. Although sending and every request is done. this memory usage is not changed.

```
from gevent import monkey;monkey.patch_all(thread=False)
import gevent
from flask import Flask, request
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/do", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ping():
    data = request.get_json()
    gevent.spawn(send_request, data)

    return 'pong'


def send_request(data):
    resp = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:25000/ping", data=data)
    if resp.text != 'pong':
        app.logger.error(resp.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    http = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", 9999), app)
    http.serve_forever()

    end_server = True
    app.logger.info("Server will be closed")
```

I think this python uses all available 65535 file count.
How can I limit python to use less file count than I configured in limit.conf file?

Answer (score 1):

python seems not reuse socket when it busy, so It makes socket over an over again until limit.conf nofile limit when sending request in spawn.

So, I just gave a limit for this python process.

```
import resource
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (1024, 1024))
```

== updated ==

But requests library still consumes a lot of memory..

I just decided to use tornado http server and AsyncHttpClient with this options below,

```
AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.simple_httpclient.SimpleAsyncHTTPClient", max_clients=1000)
tornado.netutil.Resolver.configure("tornado.netutil.ThreadedResolver")
```

you need to write this code on global area below "import" stuffs.

and used gen.moment after finishing request to send it immediately.

```
@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    self.write("pong")
    self.finish()
    yield gen.moment
    resp = yield self.application.http_client.fetch("...url...", method='POST', headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                                           body=json.dumps({..data..}))
```